# “Eine Menge von Fehlern” or “eine Menge Fehler”?

Tags: preposition

Can one say “eine Menge von Fehlern” instead of “eine Menge Fehler”?

> Er macht eine Menge Fehler, wenn er Deutsch schreibt.

Will it be still be grammatically wrong if one says:

> Wir machen alle eine Menge von Fehlern.

Is the preposition *von* only used for style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In daily German the version without preposition is by far the more idiomatic one. The von-version while probably not totally wrong sound odd, at least to me. It definitely doesn't sound like higher German.
Technically both versions exist and have different meanings.

> Eine Menge X

means a

> A lot of X

This uses *Menge* in the colloquial meaning of *mass*. But the word has a mathematical meaning, too. I don't know the exact term but a mathematical *Menge* can consist of one element only. So

> Eine Menge von X...

is

> A set of X...

Comment: Isn't the mathematical *Menge* a *set*?

Comment: Yep, in mathematical parlance “eine Menge von Fehlern” is “a set of mistakes”. Unfortunately I have lost the ability to gauge how these sound to non-mathematicians.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... I think there might be a certain ring to it for people who have been paying some attention in math in school, a ring that might fade over time. As for people who didn't pay that much attention... I'd say they'd go for "voll die Fehler" anyway ;)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz It sounds like "a set of mistakes whose cardinality is not a small nmber"